# Stored procedure to update the count

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the below 2 SQL tables

```
Table 1
Id | Data | Values
1  | rfsd | 23
2  | tfgy | 45
3  | rfff | 23


Table 2

Id | Fields | Counts
1  | 23     |   0 
2  | 45     |   0
```

As you can see, the Counts field is 0. I want to see 'Fields' column in table 2 and compare then with the 'Values' column in table 1 and increment the count whenever the value is present in 'Values' field.

The final result should show like this

```
Table 2
Id | Fields | Counts
1  | 23     |   2
2  | 45     |   1
```

This will be the counts since 23 appear twice and 45 appear once in the 'Values' field of table 1.

Can someone please let me know how to write a stored procedure for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a stored procedure.

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT
    VALUES
    , COUNT(*) AS Count2
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    VALUES
)
UPDATE t2
SET Counts = t1.Count2
FROM
    Table2 t2
    JOIN t1 ON t2.Fields=t1.Values
```